# Are all the points located at the same plane having the same polar angle, $\phi$?

Tags: geometry

Assuming that I have a plane, defined by the equation

$x+y+z=c$

Can I conclude that for any points ${x,y,z}$ that satisfies the above plane equation, they all have the same polar angle, $\phi$, as defined in [Spherical Coordinates system](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html)?

[image]

I strongly believe this is true, but I can't wrap my head around to prove it. Any idea how to prove/disprove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the polar angle $\phi$ to be everywhere equal, the ratio $\frac{z}{r},$ where $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2},$ should be constant.
Hence, we should have 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x + y + z = c\\ 
\frac{z^2}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} = k
\end{matrix}\right.$$
which clearly doesn't hold $\forall x,y,z$ (try $(0,0,1)$ and $(1,0,0)$ if you still haven't made up your mind).

The angle that is equal for all $x,y,z$ is the angle between the normal vector $\vec{n} = (1,1,1)$ and any of the axes.

By the way, there is a formula relating normal vector and polar angle: $$\vec{n} = \frac{d\vec{t}}{d\phi}$$
Where $\vec{t}$ is the tangent vector.

Answer (score 1):

The locus of points where $\phi$ is a constant in $(0,\pi)$ is a cone (except when  $\phi=\pi/2$). So typically the values of $\phi$ on a plane will not be constant.

Answer (score 0):

When a plane cuts a sphere it produces a small flat circular patch.

One simple example is   A z + B x = C, a plane perpendicular to  x- z- plane

When you convert it to spherical coordinates, you note that there must be involvement of $\theta, \phi $ together, perhaps you note also the source of your conceptual error.

It is only on cones with axis of symmetry on z axis that $ \phi $ is constant.